# serialization of class with const members using Boost

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, constructor, constants

Consider the following code snippet

```
class tmp1
{
    const int a_;
    const double b_;   
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int ver)
    {
        ar & a_ & b_ ;
    }

public:
    tmp1(const itype a , const ftype b) : a_(a), b_(b)
    {}
};
```

I can write the object to a file, by doing

```
tmp1 t1(2, 10.0);    
std::string filename ="D:/Temp/demofile.txt";
std::ofstream ofs(filename);    
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
oa<<t1;
```

I would like to construct another instance of `tmp1` by reading the file. Ideally I would like this to happen in a second constructor, that takes the file name and constructs it. How Do I accomplish this?

I tried

```
tmp1 t2(10, 100.0);
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
ia>>t2;
```

but VS2012 compilation fails with following message

```
archive/detail/check.hpp(162): error C2338: typex::value
4>          \boost\boost_1_67_0\boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp(611) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::check_const_loading<T>(void)' being compiled
4>          with
4>          [
4>              T=const itype
4>          ]
```

which I assume due to members being `const`. I thought boost would cast away the const qualifier but seems not the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is "non-default constructors" in the documentation:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

You need to write an overload for

```
template<class Archive, class T>
void load_construct_data(
    Archive & ar, T * t, const unsigned int file_version
);
```

so for class Foo, which for example is constructed with an integer and a string, you would provide:

```
template<class Archive>
void load_construct_data(
    Archive & ar, Foo * t, const unsigned int file_version
)
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
    ar >> a >> b;
    new (t) Foo(a, std::move(b));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But this may lead to bugs since read and write routines are different, correct? Why would it be preferred over  `ar & const_cast<int &>(a_) & const_cast<double &>( b_) ;`?

Comment: @user6386155 this is probably down to your own preferences

Comment: Some day you gotta teach me how to get so many upvotes with boost answers :)

Comment: @RichardHodges The approach `ar & const_cast<int &>(a_)` I saw it in boost documentation. Is it safe though? I feel this may lead to undefined behavior

Comment: @user6386155 accessing an object through a const_cast is only valid if the object is originally mutable. In your case it's not, so what you are proposing is undefined behaviour. Furthermore, the cast method requires that Foo is default-constructible. This is not logical for an object with const members.

Comment: @sehe total luck in this case I can assure you. Your problem is that you know too much and therefore give epic answers to really hard questions. Only the OP and about 3 other people in the world know what you're talking about :)

Comment: @RichardHodges it's the boost effect, really. Today I answered 1 (one) answer outside of the tag, because someone linked it in Lounge<C++>. Lo and behold, votes! Thanks for the kind words, your posts have been quite a good source for learning for me too.